# Firebug Script Panel Clears

Tags: firebug

I'm usually able to use Firebug fine but I'm working on a page now where the Firebug Script panel at the bottom clears when I select a button on the page that opens the page gallery. The source code that was in the Script panel is replaced by the message: Reload the page to get source for [my site]:
[image]

If I reload the source the page comes down without the gallery opened and as soon as I select GALLERY to open it the source in the Script window goes away again. The result is that I'm unable to debug problems related to the gallery.

One way I've found to get Firebug to run for one page load is to select  "Clear Activation List" in the Firebug dropdown at the upper right and then restart Firebug and reload the page. The next Gallery open doesn't destroy the Firebug script code and I'm able to debug normally and open and close the gallery without losing the Script code. But the next time I reload the page, I have to start over again with "Clear Activation List" sequence

Opening the gallery issues an ajax request to the server to download images into the gallery div. Somehow that is colliding with Firebug

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can avoid having to issue Clear Activation List each page load?

Thanks

Comment: I have only seen this when there are redirects on the server side for the script file in question. Is gallery inline, or is it an external js file?

Comment: The ajax call to load the gallery calls a PHP file that accesses the image files on the server.  The PHP creates img tags with src=[fileThumb] and it all ends up back in div#gallery on the client.